# Rails replacing '\n' to '<br/>' issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The input is a textarea type

so i got the data from the controller like this,

```
'firstline \n secondline \n thirdline"
```

i want to change this to

```
'firstline <br/> secondline <br/> thirdline"
```

I googled, and found this.

```
description = appointment[:description].to_s.gsub(/\n/, "<br/>")
```

but the weird thing is if i print this, it shows a weird text like this,

code,

```
<%=Rails.logger.debug("***description***" + description)%>
```

result,

```
<br/>3rd linen***1st line
```

the more weird thing is, i have to put this params to call a javascript function like this,

```
<span class="hotspot" onmouseover="tooltip.show(<%=user_list%>,&quot;<%=description%>&quot;);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">
     <%=h appointment[:users] %>
</span>
```

focus on the <%=description%>

in here i got an error, and shows like this,

```
<span class="hotspot" onmouseover="tooltip.show([],&quot;1st line
&lt;br/&gt;2nd line
&lt;br/&gt;3rd line&quot;);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

any good idea?

Comment: Try to use "#{description}" instead and show the page source code

Comment: You would want to use `raw` method to insert html tags.

Comment: Wow rails gives a fantastic function. if somebody have problem like me. just use simple_format(param). it makes the tags automatically. awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
"firstline \n secondline \n thirdline".to_s.gsub(/\n/, "<br/>").html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work

```
desc = appointment[:description].to_s
description = desc.split("\n").join("<br/>")
```

Comment: I've never seen anyone sub strings like, that, props for being either clever, or too stuborn to look up the api :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
description = appointment[:description].to_s.gsub(/\n/, "<br/>").html_safe
```